# Floating action button is not showing in api 24

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

FAB in below code is showing in api 29 phone, but not in api 24 phone. How can in solve this?
I an using material design library, and navigation components.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.HomeFragment">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: API 24]
[image: API 29]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
    />
```

Comment: Maybe you can search the errors for the Floating Action Button, in logcat, and if you want, post them in question. Might help :)

Comment: Seriously, I don't know how to recreate this. Your code, when i import it into new project, works fine.